# Removing graph nodes without changing number labels for the nodes

Tags: charts, matlab

I have a graph with vertices labeled 1 to n. I have a mapping from the labels to positions that I use to visualize the graph in three spatial dimensions. Now, I randomly remove arbitrary number of nodes using rmnode. But this messes up my mapping from number labels to positions. Is there an option to remove the nodes without changing the labels? In principle, I know I could try to dynamically change the mapping but I am trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: well, then you need to remove the nodes in the mapping, no? It would make more sense to adapt your new code to standard matlab functionality rather than otherwise.

Comment: that was my question. If avoidable, I don't want to just remove nodes as I have to dynamically change the mapping in that case. My question was whether it is avoidable by standard matlab functionality.

Comment: the mapping is defined from the numbers to positions. Just removing some entries in this mapping does not restore it to the correct form (i.e. the original mapping which assigns the vertices to some positions)

Comment: How are you plotting the nodes (and their labels)? Please post a small example with code that can be run as is

Comment: It got resolved. I could just change the mapping of the vertices to be deleted to a single point far away (keeping the remaining mapping unchanged). This does not affect the visualization.